# [Python EVE]: Reading the request parameters values in Python EVE

Tags: python, rest, eve

I am developing a web application using python eve. I have few endpoints exposed . I have an endpoint named persons , there is a field in the db schema userid . I want to populate that field using a random string that is generated after reading the request parameters.

My question is how can I read those parameters . I was not able to find the syntax for the same in Eve Documentation .

Any help in this regard would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

I guess something like this would work:

```
from eve import Eve
from flask import request

def update_inbound_docs(items):
    # retrieve request parameter, if present
    my_arg = request.args.get('key') 
    for document in items:
        # update document 'userid' field according to my_arg
        # value. replace with custom logic.
        document['userid'] = 'bingo' if my_arg else 'ack!'

app = Eve()

# bind your callback to the POST method for 'persons'
# endpoint. it will be invoked after a POST request 
# has been validated and before db is updated, so any 
# update to 'items' will be persisted.
app.on_insert_persons += update_inbound_docs

app.run()
```

Eve is a Flask application so you can use Flask `request` object at will. See [Database Hooks](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks) for details.

Comment: I just tried the code snippet that you provided. I am getting the following error  'app_on_insert_persons' is not defined.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided I am not able to modify the request parameters and neither I am able to print the request parameters. @nicola-iarocci Please help

Comment: when somehow I am trying to update the request parameters I am getting    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>